# PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST Node-MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, error-handling, node-mysql

I have made a simple node express server using my-sql. The server runs for few minutes but then crashes with the following message. I have tried to handle the error, but the app just throws the erro and then crashes. Please suggest the best way to handle these errors.
[image]

Code of my server:

```js
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import mysql from 'mysql';

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
dotenv.config();

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE
})

const DBNAME = process.env.DBNAME || 'students';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//GET ALL STUDENTS
app.get('/api/student', (req, res) => {
    const sort = 'percentage DESC'
    const getQuery = `SELECT * from ${DBNAME} ORDER BY ${sort}`;
    connection.query(getQuery, (error, result) => {
        if(error) {
            throw error
        } else {
            res.json(result)
        }
    });
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Running on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: check the mysql error log, if it shows an error

Comment: Yes but how do I fix that?

Comment: Add the error log here or on dba